# Matlab dll Error : -2147467259 for VBA in 64bit environment

Tags: matlab, vba, 64-bit, excel-addins

I made dll in 64bit environment using deploytool of Matlab.
The same functions and command works well in 32 bit environment.

What I have miised?

The vba code

```
Dim MCLUtil As Object
Dim bModuleInitialized As Boolean
Dim xlmagicclass As Object

Private Sub InitModule()
    If Not bModuleInitialized Then
        On Error GoTo Handle_Error
        If MCLUtil Is Nothing Then
            Set MCLUtil = CreateObject("MWComUtil.MWUtil")
        End If
        Call MCLUtil.MWInitApplication(Application)
        bModuleInitialized = True
        Exit Sub
Handle_Error:
        bModuleInitialized = False
    End If
End Sub


Sub mymagic()
     Dim R1 As Range 'Input value
     Dim R2 As Range 'Output range

     On Error GoTo Handle_Error
     Call InitModule
     Set R1 = Range("A2")     'Specify where the input value is.
     Set R2 = Range("B2:E5")  'Specify that range for the output to use.
     If xlmagicclass Is Nothing Then
         Set xlmagicclass = CreateObject("xlmagic.xlmagicclass.1_0")   
     End If
     Call xlmagicclass.mymagic(1, R2, R1)
     Exit Sub
Handle_Error:
     MsgBox ("Error: " & Format(Err.Number) & " Source: " & Err.Source & "     Message: " & Err.Description)
End Sub
```

The matlab code

```
function y = mymagic(x)
y = magic(x)
The error message

    Error: -2147467259 Source: xlmagic.xlmagicclass.1_0 Message:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been resolved by two step.

1. Simply install "MyAppInstaller_web" file in the for_redistribution folder.
2. And run the _install batch file in for_redistribution_files_only folder.